# React global ref

Tags: reactjs

I am in a situation where my project is one step away from finish line and I had to add an unexpected certain element to my site just as i was doing finishing touches.

The element in question will be in various child and parent components all over the website...

The problem I am facing is a need to access said element in one specific component which would mean I would need to pass its ref trough several components in various very confusing ways which is not something I want to do and I can't afford to restructure my entire site for just one small change.

The question I have then what would be the best approach to access that element "globally" because if I understand the way react works, it has virtual DOM and using `document.getElementByID` could cause unexpected behaviour down the line so I'm left wondering what should be doing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using redux, flux? What's the element?  a string? another component? an object?

Comment: @TomSarduy Just plain react.js the element is a simple `<div>` with some text in it, I need to access it and apply various transitions depending on the situation

Comment: Depending of your current solution and where is the locations of your components needing access to that particular new component, You probably you can use react context to avoid passing ref through several components that simply don't care about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you can use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to avoid passing *ref* through several components that simply don't need that info / property.

Keep in mind if you prevent to render an intermediate component the context update can't reach the targets below (I think in this particular case this should be no problem).

Read more about [updating context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context).

Answer (score -3):

You are going to need to either create a pure function component,(or regular component) that only returns a div with the provided data as props. Then, if not using redux or anything, you need to pass the props through to the pure function triggering an update.

```
<App updatedData={this.state.userInput}/>
```

Inside your App component...

```
<pureFunctionComponent updatedData={this.props.updatedData}/>
```

Inside your pureFunctionComponent...

```
<div>
<h1>this.props.updatedData.name</h1>
</div>
```

Basically without using redux or other state management you need to pass that dynamic data through to the end point that will be displaying it.